# Autowiring byName or byType or constructor?

Tags: spring, autowired

1)In Spring which autowiring in preferred?I am a beginner in learning springs so am not getting which ones to use frequently?Is it that the different types of autowiring have their own advantages and disadvantages?If yes then what?

2)From [Springs in action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182358)

eg:

```
<bean id="saxophone"
 class="com.springinaction.springidol.Saxophone"
 primary="true" />
```

And all the others their primary is set false.So i can only use this bean for autowiring.So what if i need other beans to autowire which are of the same `Instrument` type since `saxophone` is of the `Instrument` type and that since `saxophone` is declared primary then how will others be preferred depending upon situations?

Answer (score 1):

No `autowiring` have advantages or disadvantages. It solely depends upon you, which one to use or your project specification and architecture.

And for your particular example, you have to use `byName` autowiring.